# How can i modify indexing in a single object in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an object list to store indexes just like that:

```js
const initialIndexes = {
  0: [0,1,2],
  1: [0,1]
}
```

At this point I have a `highlightedResultIndex` variable. It gives an index like this:

```
highlightedResultIndex = 0 - case 1
highlightedResultIndex = 4 - case 2
highlightedResultIndex = 2 - case 3
...
```

And I finally try to get the following results by `highlightedResultIndex`

```
For the case 1:

result = {
 0: 0, // index from initialIndexes
 1: -1
}

For the case 2:

result = {
  0: -1,
  1: 1  // index from initialIndexes
}

For the case 3:

result = {
 0: 2  // index from initialIndexes
 1: -1
}
```

Maybe there is an easy method or there may be a certain algorithm for this, but I didn't know how to research it so I wanted to write it here. I would be glad if you help.

EDIT:

Let me put here some of examples

```js
// This is data from the server side.
const initialIndexes = {
  0: [0,1,2,3],
  1: [0,1,2],
  2: [0,1,2],
  3: [0,1,2,3,4]
}

// So, I need to index object like this by highlightedResultIndex variable

// highlightedResultIndex = 0
{
 0:0,
1:-1,
2:-1,
3:-1
}

//  highlightedResultIndex = 6
{
0: -1,
1:2,
2:-1,
3:-1
}

//  highlightedResultIndex = 10
{
0: -1,
1:-1,
2:-1,
3:0
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). It is very unclear what you want. It NOT recommended to have numeric keys in an object, then you might as well have an array

Comment: is it not clear how the -1 are selected

Comment: what is actually the question?

Comment: @cmgchess It's mean no index available of that group.

Comment: @NinaScholz The question is how do I get the `result` as you can see in the description by example cases. So, I need to that results from `initialIndexes` by `highlightedResultIndex`

Comment: please add **all** additional information to the question. what have you done?

Comment: @ysfkaya still unclear for example when highlightedindex = 6 why `1:2` and `2:-1` both have the same array in the intiial

Comment: I can't quite tell. Do you want a function that takes `highlightedResultIndex` as argument, uses initialIndexes somehow, then returns the objects in your example?

Comment: @cmgchess Because the highlighted index addresses the group(initialIndexes) in the "1" index and it's not belongs to other group indexes.

Comment: @OmarSaad It is a variable value that increases and decreases after pressing the up or down keys on the keyboard. You can think of it as a selector index that goes up and down through results as you search.

Comment: @ysfkaya you will need to explain how for 6 `{
0: -1,
1:2,
2:-1,
3:-1
}` i dont see a pattern

Comment: @cmgchess It comes from `initialIndexes[1][2]`.

Comment: do you want to get an index or the value of the arrays, which reflects the indices?

Comment: I needed results like in your answer. I tested it and it works as I want now thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the wanted index value and reduce it by the lenght of the arrays until it fits into an array.

```js
const
    initialIndexes = { 0: [0, 1, 2, 3], 1: [0, 1, 2], 2: [0, 1, 2], 3: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] },
    getIndices = n => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(initialIndexes)
        .map(([key, array]) => {
            const value = n >= 0 && n < array.length
                ? array[n]                           // or just n
                : -1;

            n -= array.length;
            return [key, value]; 
        })
    );

console.log(getIndices(0));  // { 0:  0, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1 }
console.log(getIndices(6));  // { 0: -1, 1:  2, 2: -1, 3: -1 }
console.log(getIndices(10)); // { 0: -1, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3:  0 }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I still wish I understood the question :( - the answer did not explain it either :P

Comment: @mplungjan, the given number reflects the index value of one of the value/index (which one is not clear, because the array's values are (like) the indices). for example if the given value `n` is greater or equal to the lenght of the first array take the next array and adjust the value by subtracting the length. then try with the next. if the array of the object is found, return the index (or just the value). for all other arrays take `-1`.